# Can I use AppCompat theme with Activity/FragmentActivity classes?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

### Given the following:

1. Android documentation says :

   > AppCompatActivity - Adds an application activity class that can be used as a base class for activities that use the Support Library action bar implementation.
2. I'm not considering adding action bar to my activity
3. I need some material design widgets, which I can control only through AppCompat or material theme, but the latest need API >= 21, which is not my case.
4. I tested Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar with Activity class and it works well.

--

**Is there an issue with using Activity class with AppCompat theme in my case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppCompat library is intended to make compatibility with olders API, so the Theme and all components may work well in older systems.

I think the only concern is to always use the AppCompat elements and not the regular ones.

Example, use AppCompatEditText, AppCompatTextView, etc... And always refers to they with the AppCompat (`AppCompatEditText editText;`)

I have used a lot the support library and not have others issues, considering the visual elements may be a little different when using an API minor than 21

Answer (score 0):

No.There is not issues with AppcompactActivity & support libaray. [You can refere this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html)

To gain more rich & amazing look go with support library,Try to do material design